# Big-O (O(n)) and Big-Omega (Ω(n)) time complexity of the Count(A, B, n) algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What is the big-O (O(n)) and Big-Omega (Ω(n)) time complexity of the Count(A, B, n) algorithm below in terms of n

[Algorithm Count (A, B, n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpZHD.jpg)

I did the following: 
Algorithm Count (A, B, n)

```
 Input: Arrays A and B of size n, where n is even.
             A, B store integers.                                                           # of operations:
        i <- 0                                                                                                    1
       sum <- 0                                                                                               1
       while i < n/2 do                                                                              n/2 + 1
              if A[i + n/2] < 0 then                                                                n/2 + 1
                  for j <- i + n/2 to n do                                                    n/2 + n/2+1 + … + n = n(n+1)/2
                        sum <- sum + B[j]                                                         n/2 + … + n = n(n+1)/2
               i <- i + 1                                                                                     n/2 + 1
      return sum                                                                                    _    _1______
```

The Algorithm Count runs in Big-O and Big-Omega of O(n^2) and Ω(n^2). This algorithm involves a nested "for" loop. The maximum number of primitive operations executed by the algorithm count is `0.5n^2+ n + 1` in both the worst case and best case.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to figure out if the method I adopted is correct or whether another method may be more efficient? Thanks

Comment: You are close, but the answer is not complete. Hint: the best-case and worst-case complexity are not the same in the algorithm (as you have transcribed it).

Comment: "Show all necessary steps of how you computed the complexity." Is it just me or does this sound like a homework problem?

Comment: It's actually for a test I'm trying to build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the worst case is O(n^2), while the best case is Ω(1). The best case is when you have an array of size 2, and A[1] >= 0, in which case the algorithm only has to pass through the loop once. If n can be 0 (i.e. empty arrays), then that's even better.

To illustrate the best case (n = 2, assuming 0 is not acceptable, and A[1] >= 0), let's assume that assignment operation takes constant time, C1.

```
i <- 0
sum <- 0
```

takes constant time 2*C1.

```
while 0 < 2/2 do
```

takes constant time C2.

```
    if A[0 + 2/2] < 0 then //evaluates to false when A[1] >= 0
```

takes constant time C3, and the nested for loop will never get executed.

```
    i <- i + 1
```

takes constant time C4. The loop checks invariant:

```
while 1 < 2/2 do
```

which takes C2. Then the operation returns:

```
return sum
```

which takes C5.

So the operation in the best case scenario where n = 2 and A[1] >= 0 is:

```
2*C1 + 2*C2 + C3 + C4 + C5 = O(1)
```

Now, you can argue that it should have been:

```
2*C1 + (n/2 + 1)*C2 + C3 + C4 + C5 = O(n)
```

but we already know that at best n = 2, which is constant.

In the case where the best scenario is when n = 0:

```
2*C1 + C2 + C5 = O(1)
```

Comment: O(1) doesn't mean "it takes one iteration", it means "it takes constant time". If the array is of size 2 and it only takes one iteration to complete, that's still O(n) - it's just that n is small.

Comment: And I never said that's what O(1) meant (or Ω(1) in this case). It's constant time, which means it takes constant time to move throughout the algorithm when it only needs to go through the loop once (and only does conditional checks and nothing else).

Comment: "while the best case is Ω(1)"

Comment: Precisely, that's the best case. If n=0, the algorithm doesn't even have to loop at all.

Comment: That's still O(n), but n is small. Please re-read my first comment.

Comment: I've read and understood your original comment the first time. I've updated my answer to illustrate my point.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate the input

Comment: Best-case means choosing the values in the array that give the smallest time, not choosing the size of the array.

Comment: @fgb best case covers whatever condition the input can be, which means it compasses values, size, etc. depending on what the algorithm takes. An array A with size 2 and contains something like [1, 2] will be the best case for the algorithm. If you think I'm wrong then perhaps you should post an alternative answer.

Comment: In that case, everyone would choose a size of 0 and all algorithms would be constant time in the best-case.

Comment: @fgb Not all algorithms take an input of size 0, just like not all mathematical functions share the same domain. Sure, perhaps most of them do, which is the very reason people rarely pay attention to the best case time complexity, as they don't really present significant insight into an algorithm's behavior. Like I said, if you have a different idea on the correct answer to this, you should let us know.

Comment: Look at the algorithms that take an input size of 0, or take any input size then. The time is still a constant. I already let you know, and Bohemian has told you the correct answer.

Comment: @fgb Why won't you present your case in as much details as I did? I think that will clear things up. Like I said, the best case here is where n=2. If you claim that it's O(n) where n is very small, how small does n get? Isn't 2 the smallest it can get (if we don't count zero to be an even number)? So if you say the best case is O(n) where n=2, then it's O(2)=O(1). I urge you to present your case in detail so all of us here would know.

Comment: Worst case would be if n is sufficiently large, and the upper half of the array A have values < 0. This is O(n^2) but it takes a little more math to illustrate. It is computed as summation of summation, which will yield a quadratic equation.